# C# HttpPost Progress updates to Angular 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript, http

In my Angular 6 application i have a progress bar that should show the rendering and downloading progress of a PDF file in percent. 
My Post call looks like the following:

```js
renderReport(renderObjectId: number): Observable<HttpEvent<Blob>> {
    return this.httpService.post('/render/report/' + renderObjectId, {
        observe: 'events',
        responseType: 'blob'
    });
}
```

The corresponding method in the backend looks like this

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("report/{renderReportId}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(HttpResponseMessage))]
public HttpResponseMessage PrintReport(int renderReportId)
{
    var man = new RenderingManager();
    MemoryStream pdfFileStream = man.RenderReport(renderReportId);
    return CreatePdfDownload(pdfFileStream);
}
```

The `RenderReport()` method takes a while because there is xml written, validated etc.
What i want to achieve is that in the frontend i can subscribe to the result of the `renderReport(renderObjectId: number)` and get multiple updates from the Backend like: "currently in step 5 of 12 in RenderReport()".

Is that somehow possible? Maybe manually returning a self-defined status after each method called in `RenderReport`?

Comment: Which version of ASP.Net are you using?

Comment: Sorry... .NET Framework 4.7

Answer (score 0):

You may want to run your time-consuming operation asynchronously when your API is called and return **Accepted**(202) status code immediately with a **Location** header, where you can poll continuously to get the status of the task until finished with a unique identifier maintained in-memory. As soon as the task is finished, you must delete this identifier so as to mark the completion of the task.

FYI - https://farazdagi.com/2014/rest-and-long-running-jobs

http://restalk-patterns.org/long-running-operation-polling.html

This way, you wouldn't be waiting for the result till the operation is completed but will be continuously polling to get the updates.

Comment: both links not found... 404

Comment: @CrazyEight, sorry, my bad. Updated the links